# How are these primary keys being generated?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can anyone give me some insight into how these primary keys are being generate I believe it's a combination of iterating integers, date and static char.

Heres a brief list:

```
D00009BFAA193275,
D00009C91855F146,
D00009CB07BE6324,
D00009D025B98577,
D00009DE345BA663,
D00019BC04F4D986,
D00019BFAFD46307,
D00019CE505D0440,
D00019E0BDD76923,
D00029BC0BECF381,
D00029BC0CB7A348,
D00029BC7DBEF433,
D00029CC49C31844,
D00029CE2254B377,
D00039BC03587530,
D00039BC062A8615,
D00039BC0C46E141,
D00039BF9D730237,
D00039BFA2F88765,
D00039BFAA40E841,
D00039D08CF92343,
D00039DD0968C108,
D00039E078E6B550,
D00049C7EE3CA721,
D00049D555313194,
D00049E15E300465,
D00059BC023FF739,
D00059BC054D8243,
D00059BC0ACA6533,
D00059BFA05CB726,
D00059BFA7B28215,
D00059C871860216,
D00059CAE73E4895,
D00059E0C2FF8179,
D00059E219CE7129,
D00069BC788D6181,
D00069BFA84E5322,
D00069C223670823,
D00069D1DF229381,
D00069D4E7C08648,
D00069DF10A4E674,
D00079BC0122D372,
D00079BC068F4995,
D00079BC7F66B951,
```

I'm trying to reverse engineer some appletes to do inserts and I want to maintain consistency.

I profiled the following T-SQL

```
    enter code here

01
declare @p1 int
02
set @p1=-1
03
declare @p5 int
04
set @p5=20484
05
declare @p6 int
06
set @p6=8196
07
exec sp_cursorprepare @p1 output,NULL,N'SELECT * FROM lntmuser.dbchk WHERE 0 = 1',1,@p5 output,@p6 output
08
select @p1, @p5, @p6
09
GO
10

11
declare @p1 int
12
set @p1=1073741881
13
declare @p5 int
14
set @p5=20484
15
declare @p6 int
16
set @p6=8196
17
exec sp_cursorprepare @p1 output,NULL,N'SELECT "sysid","chksum","m_date","m_time","k_id","k_type","atty","atty1","indx","flags","rec_date","rec_time","timeline","archive"
18
FROM lntmuser.dbchk WHERE 0 = 1',1,@p5 output,@p6 output
19
select @p1, @p5, @p6
20
GO
21

22
declare @p1 int
23
set @p1=-1
24
declare @p20 varchar(100)
25
set @p20 = 'A950A9CB53F2A512'
26
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 varchar(50),@P6 varchar(120),@P7 varchar(4),@P8 varchar(100),@P9 varchar(30),@P10 varchar(100),@P11 varchar(30),@P12 varchar(255),@P13 varchar(1),@P14 varchar(24),@P15 varchar(1),@P16 varchar(1),@P17 varchar(1),@P18 varchar(1),@P19 varchar(1),@P20 varchar(1),@P21 varchar(1),@P22 varchar(1),@P23 varchar(30),@P24 varchar(100),@P25 varchar(100),@P26 varchar(100),@P27 varchar(100),@P28 varchar(100),@P29 varchar(100),@P30 varchar(100),@P31 varchar(100),@P32 varchar(1),@P33 varchar(128),@P34 varchar(50),@P35 varchar(16),@P36 varchar(10),@P37 int,@P38 int,@P39 int,@P40 int,@P41 int,@P42 varchar(20),@P43 varchar(1),@P44 varchar(1),@P45 int,@P46 int,@P47 varchar(16),@P48 varchar(16),@P49 varchar(16),@P50 varchar(16),@P51 varchar(1),@P52 varchar(1),@P53 varchar(1),@P54 varchar(16),@P55 varchar(16),@P56 varchar(16),@P57 int,@P58 int,@P59 varchar(10),@P60 varchar(1),@P61 tinyint,@P62 tinyint,@P63 tinyint,@P64 tinyint,@P65 smallint,@P66 smallint,@P67 smallint,@P68 smallint,@P69 smallint,@P70 varchar(512),@P71 text',N'
27
INSERT INTO lntmuser.document ("date","time","endtime","duration","ccode","desc","staff","client","con_no","mat_ref","mat_no","filename","autoname","reminders","follow","done","notify","hide","trigger","private","billable","review","status","user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7","user8","type","template","clip_fmt","sysid","created_by","c_date","c_time","m_date","m_time","archive","billdate","alert","alarm","alarm_min","firstdate","eve_id","tod_id","con_id","mat_id","source","conflict","dur_type","chainid","previd","nextid","out_date","out_time","out_by","out_status","ch_weekend","ch_holiday","ch_adjust","ch_alert","ch_mail","ch_units","ch_count","ch_level","ch_shift","astaff","memo")
28
VALUES (@P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6,@P7,@P8,@P9,@P10,@P11,@P12,@P13,@P14,@P15,@P16,@P17,@P18,@P19,@P20,@P21,@P22,@P23,@P24,@P25,@P26,@P27,@P28,@P29,@P30,@P31,@P32,@P33,@P34,@P35,@P36,@P37,@P38,@P39,@P40,@P41,@P42,@P43,@P44,@P45,@P46,@P47,@P48,@P49,@P50,@P51,@P52,@P53,@P54,@P55,@P56,@P57,@P58,@P59,@P60,@P61,@P62,@P63,@P64,@P65,@P66,@P67,@P68,@P69,@P70,@P71)',0,0,0,0,'','','','','','','','','','','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','','','','','','','','','','','','',
29
'DA4829E85A36A323','EC',-1,0,0,0,0,'','','',0,0,'','','','','','','H','','','',0,0,'','',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'',''
30
select @p1
31
GO
32

33
declare @p1 int
34
set @p1=-1
35
declare @p2 int
36
set @p2=0
37
declare @p5 int
38
set @p5=20484
39
declare @p6 int
40
set @p6=8196
41
declare @p7 int
42
set @p7=0
43
exec sp_cursorprepexec @p1 output,@p2 output,N'@P1 varchar(16)',N'SELECT "date","time","endtime","duration","ccode","desc","staff","client","con_no","mat_ref","mat_no","filename","autoname","reminders","follow","done","notify","hide","trigger","private","billable","review","status","user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7","user8","type","template","clip_fmt","sysid","created_by","c_date","c_time","m_date","m_time","archive","billdate","alert","alarm","alarm_min","firstdate","eve_id","tod_id","con_id","mat_id","source","conflict","dur_type","chainid","previd","nextid","out_date","out_time","out_by","out_status","ch_weekend","ch_holiday","ch_adjust","ch_alert","ch_mail","ch_units","ch_count","ch_level","ch_shift","astaff","memo"
44
FROM lntmuser.document WHERE "sysid" = @P1 ',@p5 output,@p6 output,@p7 output,'DA4829E85A36A323'
45
select @p1, @p2, @p5, @p6, @p7
46
GO
```

Comment: how do I mark code block'ss ???

Comment: I did it for you but you can select the text you want and press  the `{}` button

Comment: @conrad err I think I screwed it up again, sorry

Comment: assigned a project and the initial employee left the company, eh?

Comment: @user574663  it looks like you tried the blockquote `"`. This adds `>` and is used for quoting text. I rolled it back for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a 16 digit UniqueIdentifier set by sql server (similiar to identity with integers, or autonumbering).  Also, looks like Hex, so I'd be curious if they translate into anything comprehensible.

Comment: The D is a constant for Document the rest I'm unsure of ... But looking at the procedure it looks like its coming from three different spots

Answer (score 0):

Profiling the TSQL code and trying to guess how its being generated probably isn't the way to go.

Instead you should grab a java disassembler and decompile the code look for what's inserting the records.

Comment: Sorry that was a guess from the word "appletes" which I took to mean a Java Applets. Also since you didn't start there I guessed you didn't have the source code. Probably too many assumptions on my part.